# Sharepoint 2010 Application Page Localization problem

Tags: localization

I'm having a problem with localizing Application Pages on sharepoint server 2010.

The problem is as follow:

-I created a site collection with a Spanish default language.

-The root web site created by the sharepoint opens with default language (Spanish) with no problem.

-However when I open a deployed Application Page on the site it appears initially * with English language. *(important note: this only happens when the application  page is requested for the first time after that if you refreshed the page or opened it from different machine or browser it will appear with Spanish language).

Is there a solution to avoid this behavior since I don't want the English language page to appear at all.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have alternate languages enabled on the site, so that both the Spanish and the English are available through the SharePoint 2010 MUI, and that your deployed Application Page has localization in English and Spanish using resource files.

The way that the SharePoint 2010 MUI decides its own user interface language is using a cookie named LCID.  This cookie will also change the thread's locale early in the process, which should theoretically make the application page load the appropriate resource file, matching the locale ID in the cookie.

If that's the case, setting that cookie (at your own risk, since SharePoint's MUI could change it or have a different scope or expiry for a cookie of the same name) before the user's browser requests that page may set the thread's locale before the first call to the Application Page.